# Script returns null from Nagios but not when ran localy

Tags: bash, nagios

I wrote a simple nagios command to check the change of a value over 1 second

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME=$1
COMMUNITY=$2
OID=$3
WAITTIME=1
echo "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H $HOSTNAME -C $COMMUNITY -o $OID" > /tmp/csnmp_comand
VAR1=`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H $HOSTNAME -C $COMMUNITY -o $OID|cut -d"=" -f2|sed 's/[a-Z]//'`
/bin/sleep $WAITTIME
VAR2=`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H $HOSTNAME -C $COMMUNITY -o $OID|cut -d"=" -f2|sed 's/[a-Z]//'`
CHANGED=`/usr/bin/expr $VAR2 - $VAR1`
BPS=`/usr/bin/expr $CHANGED / $WAITTIME`
echo "OK $BPS|bps=$BPS" > /tmp/check_snmptest
echo "OK $BPS|bps=$BPS"
exit 0
```

And I wrote a service calling this script

```
define command{
    command_name    snmp_cps
    command_line     /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_cps '$HOSTADDRESS$' '$_HOSTSNMPCOMMUNITY$' '$ARG1'
}
```

When I call The script manually ( Even as the nagios user ) I get

```
OK 233|bps=233
```

Or something like that, but when I schedule this command it returns null and sets it to critical

Also My host.cfg is

```
define host{
    use     generic-host
    host_name   asa5505.customer.local
    alias       Options ASA 5505
    address     asa5505.customer.local
    _SNMPCOMMUNITY  SetSecurly
}
define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       asa5505.customer.local
        service_description             Outside Interface PBS
        check_command                   snmp_cps!1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.16
}
```

With a few changes ( hostname and snmpcommunity )

Comment: I have a work arround now, I use check_by_ssh on the local host, With a few minor modifications ( For some reason sed was giving me issue's via check_by_ssh ) But after I modifyed it slightly it works, I would prefer to not have to pipe it though ssh though so if anyone has an idea as to what i am doing wrong let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

It was the quotes, I needed to use " instead of '

Comment: Where did you make this change? In the bash script? In the nagios service definition?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while configuring hadoop datanode monitoring plugin on centos 6(64-bit). I solved this issue of "nagios status information null" by following the below configuration.

**On nrpe client machine**

**Edit /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg**

command[check_hadoop_datanodes]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_hadoop_datanode.pl -H name-node-ip

**On Nagios server machine**

**Edit /etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg**

define command {

```
   command_name check_nrpe
   command_line /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ 
    }
```

**Edit /etc/nagios/servers/master-hdp.cfg**

define service{

```
    use                            generic-service
    host_name                      master-hdp 
    service_description            check datanodes status
    check_command                  check_nrpe!check_hadoop_datanodes
```

}

After this restart nagios server

service nagios restart

Any Suggestions regarding this post are appreciable. thank you